# Running alpine Linux with qemu

Tags: qemu, alpine-linux

I have try to run an alpine Linux in an emulated environment this way:

```
$ wget https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/releases/x86/alpine-netboot-3.16.1-x86.tar.gz
```

I have untar the archive and run:

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 256 -kernel boot/vmlinuz-lts -initrd boot/initramfs-lts -append "console=ttyAMA0 ip=dhcp alpine_repo=http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/" -virtfs local,path=/xxxx/mylocalfolder,mount_tag=mytag1,security_model=passthrough -nographic
```

My terminal is blank ! I need to remove the -nographic argument to make it work. It works fine without this argument. But i need to run it through ssh so how can How can i do ?

I want to share a folder between the host machine and the emulated computer (see virtfs option). Here is what i've type in the virtual machine:

```
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio mytag1 /mnt
```

I get this error:

> mount: mounting mytag1 on /mnt failed: No such device

I do not understand why. Any idea ?

I will have to run several times the qemu-system-i386 command. I How can i automatically run commands on the virtualized environnement when it is up ? (apk add for example) And is it possible to specify an alpine_repo which is a local file instead of http ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this

Answer (score 0):

Something is strange about your command line. You're running an i386 kernel, but you pass "console=ttyAMA0". ttyAMA0 is the typical serial terminal device name for Arm boards, not for x86 PCs. Where did you get this command line from ?

The terminal is therefore blank because you have not correctly told the guest to use a valid serial terminal device for the hardware it's running on. (It's also possible that the guest needs further configuration to work with a serial terminal: typically x86 PCs do not use serial consoles, so guest OSes are often not set up to work that way out of the box.)

Comment: Thanks you are true about ttyAMA0 ! I think i've read ARM tutorials. Thanks a lot

Comment: In general you can't take a tutorial for one architecture and expect it to just work on another. Machine types, defaults, behaviours are often different.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking tty's were exactly the same on the different architectures. And do you know why 9p mounting does not work ? Thanks